# jQuery search plugin (jSearch) searching more than one area

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter, jquery-plugins

Hey all I am using the jQuery plugin called [jSearch](https://github.com/jonmalave/jSearch) and I have the following code that currently allows me to search some tags within the said class name:

```
var jSearch = (function () {
   var input = $('#searchTxtBox');
   var items = $('#inventory .select3-multiple-selected-item');

   input.keyup(function () {
       var input = $(this).val();

       switch (true) {
           case input === '':
              items.css('opacity', '1');
              break;
           default:
              items.css('opacity', '0.2');
              items.filter('[data-searchBox*="' + input.toLowerCase() + '"]').css('opacity', '1');
              break;
       }
   });
}());
```

And some of the HTML:

```
<div class="cssMadeTbl-cell">
    <label class="control-label" data-base="NEW_Project" data-definedas="text" data-required="True" for="inventory"></label>
    <div style="float: right;">
        <input class="tips" data-tooltip="example 1" id="searchTxtBox" name="searchTxtBox" placeholder="Search..." type="search" value=" ">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span data-db="bomStatus" class="bomClass" data-id="The Status">The Status</span>
        <span id="lblBG"></span>
        <div class="input-group-addon" style="width: 33px;">
            <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,+DQo8L2c+DQo8L2c+DQo8L2c+Qo8L2c+DQo8L2c+DQo8L3N2Zz4NCg==" id="iconImg_currentUsers" style="width: 20px; height:20px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <span id="inventory" class="tips form-control input-sm" data_tooltip="example 1" data-cnt="0">
                <div class="select3-multiple-input-container">
                    <span class="select3-multiple-selected-item" data-item-id="1" data-searchbox="pending">Pending</span>
                    <span class="select3-multiple-selected-item" data-item-id="2" data-searchbox="approved">Approved</span>
                    <span class="select3-multiple-selected-item" data-item-id="3" data-searchbox="denied">Denied</span>
                    <span class="select3-multiple-selected-item" data-item-id="ADDtab_100954500" data-searchbox="add item">ADD ITEM</span>
                    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" class="select3-multiple-input" placeholder="">
                    <span class="select3-multiple-input select3-width-detector"></span>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works just fine for the above area. But the problem is that, on that same page, I have more **InventoryXX** id's that I am in need of adding the search box too as well. These range from **Inventory** to **Inventory18**.

I know I could do something like this:

```
var jSearch1 = (function () {
var input = $('#searchTxtBox');
var items = $('#inventory .select3-multiple-selected-item');
[more code here....]

var jSearch2 = (function () {
var input = $('#searchTxtBox');
var items = $('#inventory1 .select3-multiple-selected-item');
[more code here....]

var jSearch3 = (function () {
var input = $('#searchTxtBox');
var items = $('#inventory2 .select3-multiple-selected-item');
[more code here....]
[etc etc...]
```

But that would look really messy...

How can I modify this jQuery script in order to accommodate all those **Inventory** id's but still have each separate from each other?

Answer (score 0):

Try to omit the `#inventory`:

```
var items = $('.select3-multiple-selected-item');
```

or modify the selector this way if you need to target `#inventory*` only:

```
var items = $('[id^="inventory"] .select3-multiple-selected-item');
```